# Chef-provisioning not picking up convergence options

Tags: ruby, windows, server, chef-infra, devops

Working with chef-provisioning to provision a set of Windows Server 2012 VMs using the following convergence_options.

```
  convergence_options: {
    chef_config: "ssl_verify_mode :verify_none", # String containing additional text to inject into client.rb
    chef_version: '12.18.31',
    install_msi_url: 'https://packages.chef.io/files/stable/chef/12.18.31/windows/2012r2/chef-client-12.18.31-1-x64.msi',
    ignore_failure: [259, 35, 37]
  }
```

Per documentation the ignore_failure property should ignore failures for the specified exit codes however it appears that the property is not having any effect at all.

Convergence failures on provisioned machines (from non-zero exit codes on reboot) are still stopping the entire provisioning operation.

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `converge` on resource 'machine[dvps01]'
================================================================================

RuntimeError
------------
Error: command '$env:path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'MACHINE');chef-client -l auto' exited with code 259.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please paste whole machine resource call.

Comment: ignore_failure can ignore result code on specific resources. Your hash here seems to be what you pass to the chef_config property, which has no chance of being right, if it's for a `machine` resource options, then ignore_failure should be True or False. As Szymon said, give the whole picture or we can't help

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation, simply passing `ignore_failure` as a convergence option does not seem to be sufficient.

I had to make sure that the `driver.rb` included:

```
require 'chef/provisioning/convergence_strategy/ignore_convergence_failure'
```

I also consulted tests in the chef-provisioning repo to see how they expected the `ignore_failure` functionality to work. In `ignore_convergence_failure_spec.rb` we see the following:

```
  let(:test_class) do
    t = TestConvergeClass.new(convergence_options, test_error)
    t.extend(Chef::Provisioning::ConvergenceStrategy::IgnoreConvergenceFailure)
    t
  end
```

To that end, I added the following to `convergence_strategy_for` in `driver.rb`:

```
machine.extend(Chef::Provisioning::ConvergenceStrategy::IgnoreConvergenceFailure)
```

All of this resulted in the expected behavior of `ignore_failure` such that client converge failures were ignored.